# How to change the location of a new vertical split?

Tags: split

The question is somewhat straightforward. To open a vertical split, I use: `:vs`. When opening a vertical split, I'd like to initialize it with a file directly.

If I do `:vs myfile.txt` this will move the file I am currently working on to the right and open `myfile.txt` on the left of the split.

Rather, I would like the opposite to happen: the file I am working on before the vertical split stays on the left, and `myfile.txt` opens on the right of the split.

Comment: You can change the orientation later with <Ctrl-w> [H|J|K|L] keys. In you specific case you can use <Ctrl-w> L

Comment: <Ctrl-w> closes my terminal window. <Ctrl-Shift-w> tapped twice makes me change splits.

Comment: What terminal are you using?

Comment: @NabarunChatterjee Not sure if that's how you check but `echo $TERM` returns `xterm-color`

Comment: Are you using the default Terminal app in os because that closes with <Command-w>.

Comment: @NabarunChatterjee Yes I am. I am using ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use:

```
:botright vsp myFile.txt
```

See [`:h botright`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#:botright):

> Execute {cmd}.  If it contains a command that splits a window,
>           it will appear at the bottom and occupy the full width of the
>           Vim window.  When the split is vertical the window appears at
>           the far right and occupies the full height of the Vim window.

---

**EDIT** Credit goes to [ingo](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/9308/how-to-change-the-location-of-a-new-vertical-split/9310?noredirect=1#comment16180_9310) for this one:

You can make `botright` the default behavior by using the `splitright` option in your vimrc. In this configuration `topleft` can be used to open a split on the left.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks

Comment: @solalito if you want this to be the default behaviour, you can set the `splitright` option and then use `:vs myFile.txt` to open the new file on a vertical split to the right.
To open a split on the left in this configuration, you can then use `topleft vs myFile.txt`.

Comment: @Ingo Thanks for the tip, that makes things easier!

Comment: Note that having `'splitright'` set won't always produce the same results as using `:botright`. e.g. Try both `:vs` and `:botright vs` when your window already contains two horizontal splits.

Comment: @Rich, what if you also set `'splitbelow'`? Source: https://thoughtbot.com/blog/vim-splits-move-faster-and-more-naturally

Comment: @ma11hew28 That doesn't affect the behaviour I was talking about, which is the bit in the documentation quoted in the answer: **"and occupies the full height of the Vim window"**. Try out the commands I mentioned and you should see the difference.